# Error in prediction formula for GPflow SGPR?

Tags: gpflow, gaussian-process

I believe there is an error in the next-to-last equation in this  [GPflow documentation page](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/theory/SGPR_notes.html). I provide details [here](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/%7Erapela/gpflow/wrongPredictionEq.pdf). Can this be right?

Comment: this would probably be better raised as a github issue on gpflow github than a question here

Comment: and if on stack exchange, probably not on stack overflow. have suggested migration

Comment: thanks @joel. This is already the gpflow github issue https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1753 but I decided to post it here with the hope to get some feedback.

Comment: It looks like you've made a minor mistake in copying from the docs, you used `Kuu⁻¹ Λ Kuu⁻¹ = L⁻ᵀ B⁻¹ L⁻¹`, but in the documentation page it actually reads `Kuu⁻¹ Λ⁻¹ Kuu⁻¹ = L⁻ᵀ B⁻¹ L⁻¹`, which should resolve your issue. I've also commented on the GitHub issue. Thank you anyways for carefully going through the docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the third-to-the-last equation in this [GPflow documentation page](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/theory/SGPR_notes.html), as show in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWX0w.png), and further explained [here](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/theory/SGPR_notes.html). Using this corrected equation, my [previous proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70947406/15750468) of the last equation in this [GPflow documentation page](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/theory/SGPR_notes.html) greatly simplifies, as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVZop.png), and further explained [here](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/%7Erapela/gpflow/proofPredictionMean2.pdf).

Comment: If you've figured out, what the correct equations should actually be, it'd be great if you could open a pull request to contribute the fix!:)

Comment: I did it yesterday night @STJ, here is the [link](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/pull/1784), that I hope you approve :)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre could you please explain why you deleted my previous answer, if I followed the previous suggestion by radrow to include elements of the proof in the answer? I decided to do this by adding an image, since Latex is difficult in stackoverflow.